# How could i know which files changed in my branch

Tags: git, gitlab

In my gitlab-ci i want to lint only changed files with varios linters. 
Gitlab ci checkout is in detached head state.

Sometimes command 
`git --no-pager diff --name-only $(git branch -q -r --contains) $(git merge-base origin/HEAD HEAD)` 
works as expected. sometimes not. i think that is because of commit containt in more than one branch in case of rebasing or similar

Command `git --no-pager diff --name-only $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) $(git merge-base origin/HEAD HEAD)` works well in not detached mode

Comment: Im confused on the scenario. Can you explain why `git status` doesn't work for you and why you're doing those complicated git commands?

Comment: @chevybow say i push a commit to a server. I want that server to lint the files changed in that commit (or set of commits). Git status reports clean. Diff with the name-only gets me a list of files. The trick is choosing the commits for the diff. OP: why rev-parse HEAD? Diff accepts HEAD as a name.